# Help me to Resolve this Unit Test

Tags: apex, unit-test

[image: Only this part my test Class not covering plz help me to resolve this issue]

> here is the my Class

```
public class HrtoCandidateHrs 
{

    public   CandidateHr__c c;
    public HrtoCandidateHrs(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            c=new CandidateHr__c();

    }

    public pagereference createCandidateHrs()
    {
       id HRid= apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        HumanResource__c HR=[select id,name,Rank__c,Last_Name__c,Submitted__c from HumanResource__c where id=:HRid];
        CandidateHr__c  ca=[select id,name,HumanResource__c from CandidateHr__c  where HumanResource__c=:hr.id];
      if(ca.HumanResource__c!=hr.id)
      {
        c.HumanResource__c=hr.id;
        c.name=HR.name;
        c.Last_Name__c=hr.Last_Name__c;
        c.Rank__c=hr.Rank__c;
        insert c;
        }
        else
        {
        ca.HumanResource__c=hr.id;
          ca.name=HR.name;
          ca.Last_Name__c=hr.Last_Name__c;
        ca.Rank__c=hr.Rank__c;
        update ca;
         }
        pagereference p=new pagereference ('/'+Hrid);
                hr.Submitted__c=true;
                update hr;

        return p;
    }

}
```

> Here is the Test Class it only covered 27%.

```
@isTest

public class HrtoCandidateHrs_TC 

{

    static testMethod void testMthd()
    {
        CandidateHr__c c=new CandidateHr__c ();
        HumanResource__c h=new HumanResource__c ();
       ApexPages.StandardController sc=new ApexPages.StandardController (h);
        HrtoCandidateHrs hr=new HrtoCandidateHrs(sc);
        hr.createCandidateHrs();
       h.name='testH';
    insert h;
    CandidateHr__c ca=[select id,name from CandidateHr__c where HumanResource__c=:h.id];
    system.assertNotEquals(ca.HumanResource__c ,h.id);
    c.name='test1';
    c.HumanResource__c=h.id;
    insert c;        
    system.assertEquals(ca.HumanResource__c ,h.id);        
    c.name='test';
    update c;
   pagereference p=new pagereference ('/apex/HrtoCandidateHrs?id='+H.id);
    test.setCurrentPageReference(p);
   h.name='test1H';
   update h;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starter it looks like you are getting an error and that is why you code coverage stops.

The error is coming from the fact that there is no 'id' page parameter and thus the next query throws the "list has no rows for assignment to sObject"

So as a start you will need to set the test page reference by:

```
HumanResource__c h=new HumanResource__c ();
Pagereference pr = New PAgeReference('/apex/YOURVFPAGE?id=' + h.id;
test.setCurrentPageReference(pr);
```

This will get you past the first hurdle

The second hurdle will be on the query for CandidateHR as you did not set the value of HumanResource__c in the record you inserted......

Think all of this through. You test should be setting up data like the code expects and the users would enter. You should mimic that. Writing tests is not about code coverage, it is about asserting that you get the proper results. The code coverage will follow. Also, if you look at your code, it is VERY EASY to see why something is not covered, simply refer to the code then look at the data you created and think it through.

As a side not, in your class you should be checking for the presence of the id parameter and if it does not exist set a boolean and configure you VF page to display a good error message that no ID was found or something.....Proper error handling is always a good practice

Comment: Unable to enter into if else block..

Comment: @Krish - As your code is written you will NEVER enter the If block. You HR is the one with the id rid and you ca is the one where the human resources__c = hr.id. so your condition of the If will NEVER be met.

Comment: now changed according to your analysis even though its not covered plz check it once

Comment: @Krish - Looks same to me, it will never enter the If.